# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable error while using find_element_by_id Selenium with ChromeDriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, chrome-web-driver

Here is the html code:

```
< input class="form-control input-lg input auto-complete" id="ymMsgInput" type="text" placeholder="Type your message ..." autocomplete="off" >
```

Code:

```
i = s.find_element_by_id("ymMsgInput");
```

Python - Selenium Chrome webdriver error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#19>", line 1, in <module>
    i = s.find_element_by_id("ymMsgInput");
  File "C:\Users\vishn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 351, in find_element_by_id
    return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
  File "C:\Users\vishn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 955, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\vishn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\vishn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable
  (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.146)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.36.540470 (e522d04694c7ebea4ba8821272dbef4f9b818c91),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error says it all :

```
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable
```

This error is observed in case of **version compatibility** between the binaries which an user uses but definitely this is not your case as you are :

- Using *chromedriver=2.36*
- Using *chrome=65.0*
- Selenium version **unknown**

  Release Notes of [chromedriver=2.36](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.36/notes.txt) clearly mentions :

  > `Supports Chrome v65-66`

But, since the release of the latest *Chromedriver 2.36* [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) users had been facing issues with it. Here is one of the threads :

- [We released the latest Chromedriver 2.36](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromedriver-users/Tf3vzBMEzHg)

The root cause is related to the commit regarding :

- [Remove --disable-infobars](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/d869ab3350d8ebd95222b4a47adf87ce3d3214b1)

  So, a couple of possible solution will be to :
- To use *ChromeOptions* Class to maximize the browser.
- Remove the *option* `disable-infobars`
- An example :

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

  options = Options()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get('https://www.google.co.in')
  print("Page Title is : %s" %driver.title)
  ```

If your issue still persists consider the following :

- Upgrade *Selenium Python Client* to  current levels [Version 3.10.0](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium).
- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  **stable** [ChromeDriver v2.35](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version at *Chrome v64.x* levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.35 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.35/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *test Suite*.
- If your base *Chrome* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of Chrome.
- Execute your `Test`.

Answer (score 9):

Your exception is not about finding an element. Selenium is not able to contact Chrome. You can do couple of things.

1. Downgrade/upgrade your chromedriver based on your selenium version.
2. Pass --no-sandbox to chrome options.

   ```
   chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
   chrome = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the version issues mentioned above (e.g., pip uninstall chromedriver-binary and re-install a different version with pip install chromedriver-binary==104.0.5112.20, for example):

Leave the browser window open after running 'driver = webdriver.Chrome()' in Python! Closing it will interfere with subsequent lines using driver.get().