# selenium python send_keys stop working

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, webdriver

This short trivial code worked fine as of bef. yesterday,
but now send_keys is not working anymore:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
elem.send_keys("Hello WebDriver!")
elem.submit()
print(driver.title)
```

**This is the stack trace:**

```
C:\Users\Rui\PycharmProjects\geo\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Rui/PycharmProjects/geo/send_keys.py
debug value ('Hello WebDriver!',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Rui/PycharmProjects/geo/send_keys.py", line 5, in <module>
    elem.send_keys("Hello WebDriver!")
  File "C:\Users\Rui\PycharmProjects\geo\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 483, in send_keys
    'value': keys_to_typing(value)})
  File "C:\Users\Rui\PycharmProjects\geo\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 632, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\Rui\PycharmProjects\geo\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Rui\PycharmProjects\geo\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'
  (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.181)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.34.522940 (1a76f96f66e3ca7b8e57d503b4dd3bccfba87af1),platform=Windows NT
```

6.1.7601 SP1 x86)

```
Process finished with exit code 1
```

(the string:

debug value ('Hello WebDriver!',)

results that trying to understang what is going on, in "webelement.py" I added
this line `"print("debug value " + str(value))":`

```
def send_keys(self, *value):
    # 2018MAR25
    # send_key generating errors since 2018MAR24!
    print("debug value " + str(value))
```

And as it really prints "debug value ('Hello WebDriver!',)" I cannot understand
why "webelement.py" is complaining that "call function result missing 'value'"

Can someone enlighten me? How can i solve this issue?
I noticed that Chrome was updated to 65 around this date, could it be related?

> Windows 7 32 bit
>
> Selenium 3.11.0
>
> Python 3.6.4
>
> 2017-12-19 Chrome
>
> 65.0.3325.181 2018-03-22

Thanks,
Rec

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unknown error: call function result missing 'value' for Selenium Send Keys even after chromedriver upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49162667/unknown-error-call-function-result-missing-value-for-selenium-send-keys-even)

Comment: Check out the post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49162667/unknown-error-call-function-result-missing-value-for-selenium-send-keys-even which looks like it is equivalent to your issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable error while using find\_element\_by\_id Selenium with ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49205782/selenium-common-exceptions-webdriverexception-message-chrome-not-reachable-err)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your chrome driver seems not latest. if you are using chrome 65 then you need latest chrome driver.

Please take latest version of chrome driver from here : https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.37/

It should resolve your sendkey issue.

Comment: Sorry, Helping Hands, I was not aware of "accept", now it is done, thanks

Comment: @Rec - No problem :)