# Python Selenium WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable, when both are up to date

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

suddenly I started getting the WebDriverException error (I assume after my browser updated automatically), and it happened before so I checked my browser version and driver version. 
Browser version: 81.0.4044.92 (Official Build) (64-bit)
chromedriver version: 81.0.4044.69

And the error I'm getting is below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-124-def11676151d> in <module>
----> 1 soldStartDate = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//input[@name='daterangepicker_start']"))).click()
      2 soldEndDate = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//input[@name='daterangepicker_end']"))).click()
      3 
      4 soldStartDate.clear()
      5 soldStartDate.send_keys(searchStartDate)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py in until(self, method, message)
     69         while True:
     70             try:
---> 71                 value = method(self._driver)
     72                 if value:
     73                     return value

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\expected_conditions.py in __call__(self, driver)
    126     def __call__(self, driver):
    127         try:
--> 128             return _element_if_visible(_find_element(driver, self.locator))
    129         except StaleElementReferenceException:
    130             return False

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\expected_conditions.py in _find_element(driver, by)
    413         raise e
    414     except WebDriverException as e:
--> 415         raise e
    416 
    417 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\expected_conditions.py in _find_element(driver, by)
    409     if thrown."""
    410     try:
--> 411         return driver.find_element(*by)
    412     except NoSuchElementException as e:
    413         raise e

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in find_element(self, by, value)
    976         return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
    977             'using': by,
--> 978             'value': value})['value']
    979 
    980     def find_elements(self, by=By.ID, value=None):

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    319         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    320         if response:
--> 321             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    322             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    323                 response.get('value', None))

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable
  (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.92)
```

I have the most recent version of the chrome driver, and I don't understand why I'm getting this error. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think this is due to your browser version is upgraded to latest 81.0.4044.92 and your chrome driver is still old and not handling that upgraded browser version.So chromdriver 81.0.4044.69 supporting till browser 81.0.4044.69

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable error while using find\_element\_by\_id Selenium with ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49205782/selenium-common-exceptions-webdriverexception-message-chrome-not-reachable-err)