# Python script using Selenium/Chromedriver stopped working

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm a bit of a novice to all of this, but I had written a simple web scraper in Python a few months ago that interfaced to Chrome using Selenium and chromedriver (it used to work with v90).  I'd run this script every couple of weeks or so to get new data, but when I went to run it today it wouldn't work.  I got a message that said "chrome not reachable".  I can see where the chromedriver window launches (it says, "this window being controlled by automated software"), but my script cannot communicate with that window.  It will eventually timeout and throw the "chrome not reachable" error.

I thought that this might have to do with the latest chrome updates, so I updated my chromedriver version, but the issue persists.  Has anyone seen this recently and do you know a workaround?

I'm using:

- Python v3.9.4
- Selenium v3.141.0

And I've tried:

- ChromeDriver v92.0.4515.43
- ChromeDriver v91.0.4472.101
- ChromeDriver v90.0.4430.24

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: What is your chrome browser version ?

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49205782/selenium-common-exceptions-webdriverexception-message-chrome-not-reachable-err

Answer (score 1):

Your chromedriver and Chrome versions must match, otherwise chromedriver will not work. You can try installing an earlier version of Chrome with matching chromedriver and give it a try. You can find earlier versions here: https://www.slimjet.com/chrome/google-chrome-old-version.php

Comment: I know that the chrome and chromedriver versions must match. That is why I tried v90, 91, and 92. My main chrome browser version is v91 x.x.114. is the published v91 chromedriver not covering up to sub rev 114?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I didn't change anything; I didn't reboot, I didn't alter my code, I didn't re-download the chromedriver, but today I ran my script and it all works as normal.  I don't know what happened earlier.

This is not a great answer, but I don't want others to waste time trying to solve a non-existing problem.  Thanks all for your help and insight.