# Selenium: How to determine if WebdriverWait is really the problem?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

related to:
[ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted Element is not clickable error clicking a radio button using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62903056/elementclickinterceptedexception-message-element-click-intercepted-element-is)
and
[Debugging "Element is not clickable at point" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908249/debugging-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-error)

I want to download every 10 pdfs from every page but it stops after 110 files at page 11 giving me this error:

```
ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <a href="/dsaf/sdgf/sdg.pdf" target="_blank" title="blabla bla">...</a> is not clickable at point (498, 9). Other element would receive the click: <div id="service-nav" class="header-right">...</div>
```

I searched and found that i would need to make the webdriver wait. I applied it already but i need to also get it to work on the following line of code `i.click()`

```
for j in range(295):
    pdfs = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".title a")
    if j < 10:
        pdfs = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".title a")
    for i in pdfs:
        time.sleep(3)
        i.click()
        time.sleep(3)
    if j < 10:
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".page-next button"))))
    else:
        continue
break
```

When i replace `i.click()` with `i.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)` or

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, i))).click()
```

it doesent work as intended. Either it repeatedly download always the same pdf or downloads file 110-120 repreatedly or throws error: `invalid argument: 'value' must be a string`. How can i apply the webdriverwait thing to the `i.click()` instance?

here is the `innerHTML` of page 1

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="generator" content="defah">

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/dfh.png" type="image/png">
    <script src="/tsartj.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        var enableP = 'False';
    </script>
        
    
    <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS" href="http://afha.rss">
    

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="robots" content="index, nofollow">
    <meta name="author" content="asgd">
    <meta name="description" content="sjdfg">
    <meta name="geo.region" content="sjsrt">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fdndfd" media="all">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fdndfd" media="all">
    <script src="vfdndfd" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="fdndfd" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/fdndfd" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/fdndfd" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <title>fdndfd
    </title>
    <meta property="og:title" content="fdndfd">
    <meta property="og:type" content="Page">
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://pfdndfd">
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="fdndfd">
    <meta property="og:image" content="fdndfd">
    <script src="//fdndfd" type="text/javascript"></script><link id="rsmod_Styles" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//fdndfd">
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://fdndfd">
</head>
<body class="live script-on" data-rsevent-id="rs_780106">
    <ul id="skipnav" title="navigation">
        <li><a href="#main-nav">fdndfd</a></li>
        <li><a href="#main">fdndfd</a></li>
        <li><a href="#footer">fdndfdh</a></li>
        <li><a href="#service-nav">fdndfdn</a></li>
    </ul>

    <header id="header">
        <div class="container">
        
            <nav aria-label="fdndfd" id="main-nav" class="main-nav" aria-expanded="false">
                <button class="menu-button">
                    fdndfd
                </button>
                <div id="navigation" class="fdndfd">
                    <div class="container">
                        <nav class="service-nav only-mobil" aria-label="fdndfd">
    <ul>
        <li class="readspeaker-button" style="display: none;"><a href="https://fdndfd" title="fdndfd" rel="nofollow" onclick="readpage(this.href, 'readspeaker1'); return false;" target="_blank">fdndfd</a></li>
        <li><a href="fdndfd" title="fdndfd" target="_blank">fdndfd</a></li>
        <li><a href="fdndfd" title="fdndfd" target="_blank">fdndfd</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
                        <nav aria-label=" navigation">
                            <ul class="nav-points level-0" aria-label="fdndfd" role="menu">
                                <li tabindex="0" role="menuitem" aria-haspopup="false">
                                    <span tabindex="-1"><a href="https://fdndfd" title="fdndfd" target="_blank">fdndfd</a></span>
                                </li>
                                <li tabindex="0" role="menuitem" aria-haspopup="false">
                                    <span tabindex="-1"><a href="/fdndfd">fdndfd</a></span>
                                </li>

                                <li tabindex="0" role="menuitem" aria-haspopup="false">
                                    <span tabindex="-1"><a href="/fdndfd">fdndfd</a></span>
                                </li>
                                 <li tabindex="0" role="menuitem" aria-haspopup="false">
                                    <span tabindex="-1"><a href="/fdndfd">fdndfd</a></span>
                                </li>
                                
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="https://fdndfd" title="fdndfd"><img src="/fdndfd" width="320" height="80" alt="fdndfd"></a>
            </div>
            
            <div id="service-nav" class="header-right">
                <nav class="service-nav no-mobil" aria-label="fdndfd">
                    <ul>        
                        <li class="font-size"><button tabindex="0" id="font-size-button" title="fdndfd" aria-expanded="false">fdndfd</button>
                            <ul>
                                <li class="font-size-1"><a href="#" title="Nfdndfd">A</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="readspeaker-button" style="display: none;"><a href="https://fdndfd" title="fdndfd" rel="nofollow" onclick="readpage(this.href, 'readspeaker1'); return false;" target="_blank">Sfdndfd</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://fdndfd" title="fdndfd" target="_blank">fdndfd</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://fdndfd" title="fdndfd" target="_blank">fdndfd</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/fdndfd" title="fdndfd">fdndfd</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <nav class="meta-menu no-cart" aria-label="Nfdndfde">
                    

                <div id="fdndfd" data-for="live" class="livefdndfd">
                    <a id="fdndfd" href="https://fdndfd" title="fdndfd" target="_blank">fdndfd</a>
                    
                    <div class="wrap-fix-live">
                        <div class="bg-grey">
                            <div class="container">
                                <a href="" class="icon-close" title="fdndfd"><span>fdndfd</span></a>
                                <div class="responsive-iframe">
                                </div>
                                <a id="fdndfd" class="open-live" rel="noopener" target="_blank" href="https://fdndfd"><span class="icon-live">fdndfd</span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <!--div data-for="service" class="fdndfdlink btn">
                    <a href="https:/fdndfd" title="fdndfd" target="_blank">fdndfd</a>
                </div-->

                <!--button data-for="search" class="searchfdndfd" aria-expanded="false">
                    Suche
                </button>
                <div class="wrap-fix-search">
                    <div class="bg-grey modal-padding">

                    <form action="/fdndfd" method="post" onsubmit="return freeSearchTop();" id="tx_tltsearch" role="search" class="container container-search">
                        <label for="Search">
                            <input placeholder="fdndfd" class="search-box" id="topFreeSearch" name="SearchWords" type="text"/>
                            

<input type="hidden" value="1" name="SearchType" />
<input type="hidden" value="" name="fdndfd" />
<input type="hidden" value="" name="fdndddfd" />

                        </label>

                        <span class="icon-arrow" title="fdndfd">
                            <span tabindex="-1" class="icon-arrow-text">fdndfd</span>
                            <input class="search-submit" type="submit" value="fdndfd" />
                        </span>

                        <button tabindex="0" class="icon-close" title="fdndfd">
                            <span>fdndfd</span>
                        </button>
                    </form>

                    </div>
                </div-->
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
    </header>
    
    <main id="main">

    <div class="container include-in-search">
        <div id="keyvisual" class="keyvisual noprint">
            <img src="/fdndfd.png" width="1395" height="488" class="img-responsive" alt="">
            <div class="box-white clickable" onclick="location.href='/fdndfd';return false" title="fdndfd">
                <h1>
                    fdndfd<br>fdndfd
                </h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="keyvisualprintonly" class="keyvisual printonly">
            <h1>
                fdndfd
            </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>

  

    <div class="container breadcrumb noprint">
        <div class="mainnavi tabs transformer-tabs rs_preserve" role="tablist">
    <button class="tabtoggle"><span class="icon-plus"><span class="icon-plus-text">fdndfd</span></span></button>
    <button role="tab" aria-controls="tab-1" aria-selected="false" onclick="location.href='http://fdndfd';return false;" id="tabheader-1" tabindex="-1">fdndfd</button>
    <button role="tab" aria-controls="tab-2" aria-selected="false" onclick="location.href='http://fdndfd';return false;" id="tabheader-2" tabindex="-1">fdndfd</button>
    <button role="tab" aria-controls="tab-3" aria-selected="true" onclick="location.href='http://fdndfd';return false;" id="tabheader-3" tabindex="-1">fdndfd</button>
</div>
        <!--ul id="breadcrumb" aria-label="fdndfd">
            
            <li><a href="/fdndfd" title="fdndfd">fdndfd</a><span class="separator"></span><span class="breadcrumb-selected">fdndfd</span></li>
        </ul-->        

        <div class="share-container">
            <button data-for="fdndfd" aria-label="fdndfd" class="share icon-fdndfd" aria-expanded="false">fdndfd</button>
            <div class="share-links">
                <a href="http://www.facebook.com/fdndfd" title="pfdndfd" target="_blank"><span class="icon-facebook">fdndfd</span></a>
                <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/fdndfd" title="pfdndfd" target="_blank"><span class="icon-twitter">fdndfd</span></a>
                <a href="https://api.whatsapp.fdndfd" title="fdndfd" class="only-mobil" target="_blank"><span class="icon-whatsapp">fdndfd</span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="readspeaker1" class="rs_skip rs_preserve"></div>
    
     <noscript>
      <div class="error-message">
      <br /><br /><br />
        fdndfd
      <br /><br /><br />
      </div>
    </noscript>
     <script type="text/javascript">
      //<![CDATA[
         if (!navigator.cookieEnabled) {
             document.write('<div class="error-message"><br /><br /><br />Cookies<br /><br /><br /></div>');
         }
      //]]>
     </script>

    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(".readspeaker-button").hide();
                $('#keyvisual').addClass('noprint');
                $('.breadcrumb').addClass('noprint');
            });
        //]]>
    </script>

    
<div class="container inner-container tlt_search printcontent">
    <h2 class="screenreader">fdndfd   
        
            Page 1
        
    </h2>
  
    

        <div class="page-head-height">
            <div class="pd_resultcount">
                
                    fdndfd
                1 - 10 von 2945 

               <span class="noprint">&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" onclick="printStyle('fdndfd');return false">fdndfd</a>  &nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                <br> <br>
                 

                
                            <a href="/fdndfd?param=true" id="search-refine" title="fdndfd">fdndfd</a>
                       
            </div>
        </div>
         <div class="tlt_search_results">
             <ul class="sourceGroup" aria-label="fdndfd">
        
        
            <li class="row tlt_search_result">
                <div class="col-1 docImage" data-index="index">
                     <a href="/fdndfd.pdf" title="fdndfd (436 KB)">
                        
                        <img src="/fdndfd.png" alt="fdndfd (436 KB)">
                     </a> 
                </div>
                <div class="col-11">
                    <div class="row title">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <a href="/fdndfd.pdf" target="_blank" title="fdndfd">
                                fdndfd
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row resultinfo">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div>
                                    fdndfd
                                </div>
                            </div> 

                            
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div>
                                        fdndfd
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                             
                
                            <div class="row">
                                <div>
                                    fdndfd
                                    
                                    <span class="processlink">
                                        <a href="/Pfdndfd1" title="fdndfd">
                                            fdndfd
                                        </a>
                                    </span>
                                    
                                </div>
                                  
                            </div>

                            
                                
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
                          
            <li class="row tlt_search_result">
            .
            .
            .
            </li>

            <li class="row tlt_search_result">
            .
            .
            .
            </li>
             
            <li class="row tlt_search_result">
            .
            .
            .
            </li>

            <li class="row tlt_search_result">
            .
            .
            .
            </li>
             
            <li class="row tlt_search_result">
            .
            .
            .
            </li>

            <li class="row tlt_search_result">
            .
            .
            .
            </li>
             
            <li class="row tlt_search_result">
            .
            .
            .
            </li>

            <li class="row tlt_search_result">
            .
            .
            .
            </li>
             
            <li class="row tlt_search_result">
                <div class="col-1 docImage" data-index="index">
                     <a href="/fdndfd.pdf" title="fdndfd">
                        
                        <img src="/fdndfd.png" alt="fdndfd (435 KB)">
                     </a> 
                </div>
                <div class="col-11">
                    <div class="row title">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <a href="/fdndfd.pdf" target="_blank" title="fdndfd">
                                fdndfd
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row resultinfo">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div>
                                    fdndfd
                                </div>
                            </div> 

                            
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div>
                                        fdndfd
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                             
                
                            <div class="row">
                                <div>
                                    fdndfd
                                    
                                    <span class="processlink">
                                        <a href="/fdndfd" title="fdndfd">
                                            fdndfd
                                        </a>
                                    </span>
                                    
                                </div>
                                  
                            </div>

                            
                                
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
             
           </ul>
        <div class="tlt_search_footer"><form class="has-validation-callback"><nav class="pagination" aria-label="fdndfd"><ul><li class="page-first disable"><a role="link" aria-disabled="true" aria-label="fdndfd"><span class="icon-arrow"></span><span class="icon-arrow"></span></a></li><li class="page-prev disable"><a role="link" aria-disabled="true" aria-label="fdndfd"><span class="icon-arrow"></span></a></li><li class="tx-pagebrowse-pages pages"><ol><li class="tx-pagebrowse-current"> 1</li><li class="tx-pagebrowse-page"><button type="submit" aria-label="fdndfd" title="fdndfd" onclick="location.href='/fdndfd';return false"> 2</button></li><li class="tx-pagebrowse-page"><button type="submit" aria-label="Page 3" title="Go to page 3" onclick="location.href='/fdndfd';return false"> 3</button></li></ol></li><li class="page-next"><button type="submit" aria-disabled="false" aria-label="fdndfd" onclick="location.href='/fdndfd';return false;"><span class="icon-arrow"></span></button></li><li class="page-last"><button type="submit" aria-disabled="false" aria-label="fdndfd" onclick="location.href='/fdndfd';return false;"><span class="icon-arrow"></span><span class="icon-arrow"></span></button></li></ul></nav></form></div>
       
             <form class="has-validation-callback"><button class="btn noprint" type="submit" aria-label="fdndfd" name="Back" onclick="location.replace('/fdndfd');return false">fdndfd</button></form>
          </div>
    

    
</div>

    
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </main>

    <footer id="footer">
        <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col1">
            <h2>fdndfd<button class="icon-plus" data-for="fdndfd" aria-label="fdndfd"></button></h2>
            <ul id="kontakt">
                <li><a href="https://fdndfd" title="fdndfd" target="_blank">fdndfd</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col2">
            <h2>fdndfd<button class="icon-plus" data-for="sprache" aria-label="pfdndfd"></button></h2>
            <ul id="sprache">
                <li><a href="https://pfdndfd" title="pfdndfd" target="_blank">pfdndfd</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://pfdndfd" title="pfdndfd" target="_blank">pfdndfd</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container footer-social-media">
    <div class="row links-social-media">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/pfdndfd" target="_blank" title="pfdndfd"><span class="icon-facebook">Facebook</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
        <img src="/footer.png" width="1600" height="1005" class="bg-footer" alt="">
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </footer>

    <div class="grt-cookie grt-cookie-active" style="color: rgb(36, 36, 36); background: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
        <div class="grt-cookies-msg">
            <p class="h2 grt-cookies-header">Cookies</p>
            <p>Accept CookiesLink: <a href="https://pfdndfd" target="_blank">pfdndfd</a>.</p>
        </div>
        <span class="grt-cookie-button" style="background: rgb(0, 108, 183); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">Ok</span>
    </div>
    <script src="/pfdndfd.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- Default texts and parameters -->
    

<div id="hidden-param">
    <!-- URLs -->
    <span id="url-update-descriptors">/pfdndfd</span>
    <span id="url-descriptor-references">/pfdndfd</span>
    <span id="url-reload-speaker-persons">/pfdndfd</span>

    <!-- MESSAGES -->
    <span id="msg-unknown-error">pfdndfd</span>
    <span id="msg-reload">pfdndfd.</span>
    <span id="msg-unknown-error-page-reload">Epfdndfd</span>
    <span id="msg-empty-keywords">pfdndfd.</span>
    <span id="msg-empty-subjectareas">pfdndfd.</span>
    <span id="msg-wrong-date-format">pfdndfd</span>

    <span id="msg-no-solution-set">pfdndfd</span>
    <span id="msg-captcha-no-number">pfdndfd</span>
    
</div>



</body>
```

Comment: Can you share a link to the web site? I'm quite sure the problem is definitely not with the webdriver wait itself...

Comment: thanks for your comment. Unfortunately i cannot share. Would html help?

Comment: Maybe. But not just of that element. Preferably of the entire page.

Comment: i edited it accordingly and replaced search result 2 to 9 with `<li class="row tlt_search_result">
            .
            .
            .
            </li>`. I only replaced noninformative characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the issue is:
There are 295 pages with 10 links on each of them so as you can click `next` button each time in order to go to the next page.
The `next page` button is initially inside the visual view of the screen, however after 11 pages it becomes out of the screen or covered by some other element.
I think you should move to the next page button to bring it into the visible screen area. To do so you can instead of

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".page-next button"))))
```

try using this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time


wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
actions = ActionChains(driver)

next_btn = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".page-next button")))
time.sleep(0.2)
actions.move_to_element(next_btn).click().perform()
```

**UPD**
I see a logical problem with your code.
You just do nothing for j >= 10. So you are entering endless loop on j==10.
Also it's unclear why you sure you will have 295 pages?
Why not simply iterate until next page button is existing?
Please instead of this:

```
for j in range(295):
    pdfs = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".title a")
    if j < 10:
        pdfs = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".title a")
    for i in pdfs:
        time.sleep(3)
        i.click()
        time.sleep(3)
    if j < 10:
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".page-next button"))))
    else:
        continue
break
```

Use something like this:

```
while True:
    pdfs = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".title a")
    for i in pdfs:
        time.sleep(3)
        i.click()
        time.sleep(3)
    next_btn = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".page-next button")
    if next_btn:
        actions.move_to_element(next_btn[0]).click().perform()
        time.sleep(3)
    else:
        break
```

Comment: It works on the first 11 pages and correctly downloads the first 110 files before it enter an endless loop on page 11 again, without hitting the next-page button. Here are my chrome webdriver options:
`prefs = {"profile.default_content_settings.popups": 0, "download.default_directory": r"C:\Users\...", "directory_upgrade": True, "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True}` `driver.maximize_window()`.

Comment: Need to see the actual web page + dev tools

Comment: I have updated the code. See if now it works correct

Comment: the first 10 files work and then: `WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable` which in this situation makes no sense to me as my chrome and chromedriver versions are compatible, i checked that by `driver.capabilities`

Comment: That's strange.. As mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49205782/selenium-common-exceptions-webdriverexception-message-chrome-not-reachable-err  try setting this:

Comment: chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options)

Comment: No Sandbox doesent help, i get the same error
 `options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
prefs = {"profile.default_content_settings.popups": 0,
         "download.default_directory": r"C:\Users\..",
         "directory_upgrade": True,
         "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH, options=options)`

Comment: If so currently I have no idea what can be the problem. I didn't face with this.

Comment: rebooting turned out to be helpful although i did `tearDown(self):
    self.driver.close()`. Now i get `NameError: name 'actions' is not defined`. Therefore i placed `actions = ActionChains(driver)` before your `actions.move_to_element` command and until now it works even for page 12 and onwards. Thank you so much :)

Comment: I'm happy I could assist you!